# How to avoid "This chart has expired. Please reload."

Tags: php, html, iframe

I am currently putting a chart from another website into my own website via iframe. The iframe is working but when I logout from that website the chart becomes:

> This chart has expired. Please reload.

I believe the src of the chart changes when I logout from that website. Can you think of any solutions?

Comment: You can inspect your web page to see if the source is still there.

Comment: maybe they dont want you stealing their content

Comment: @ema.jar yes it' still there. but the problem is the jsession id of the chart i copied already changed when i logout that's why the iframe on my website became expired.

Answer (score 0):

The source might have restricted access, available only to authorized users. So it is displayed until you logged into the site.

Comment: is there any way that my src script changes when the src is changed? like automatically?